# How to prevent bootstrap column overlapping each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning using bootstrap by making simple example where I have 3 columns which size of 2, 8 and 2. I realized that at some screen size, the content inside of the columns are overlapping each other. How can I prevent this overlapping, what I expect is no matter the size of the screen is, the page always keep 3 columns and the content inside of the columns will be going down in newline.

```
<div id="SummaryList" class="sidebar-left col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 sidebar-offcanvas">
    <div class="mainTenant">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
</div>

<div id="main" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" role="main">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 rightSidebar" role="complementary" >
    <div class="container-fluid">cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</div>
</div>
```

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17967/

Answer (score 1):

It's the letters that "break" the columns. This is not a real life example, because this is most likely to never happen. To have all those letters without a space or breaking point.

You can "fix" this by adding `word-break: break-all;`. [An example.](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17967/)

But again this is not a real life problem.

**Edit**: You might find it useful to use dummy text generators like: [lipsum.com](http://lipsum.com/). Example: [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17969/)

Answer (score 0):

try this css in container `word-break:break-all`

Answer (score 0):

use below updated code to solve issue.

```css
div {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="page-container">
  <div id="mainContainer" class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">

      <div id="SummaryList" class="sidebar-left col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 sidebar-offcanvas">
        <div class="mainTenant">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
      </div>

      <div id="main" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" role="main">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 rightSidebar" role="complementary" >
        <div class="container-fluid">cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```